Azure AD B2C: localization for sign-in userflow not working
I´m trying to modify my sign-in page to use different languages.
When I switch the language (e.g. via 'Run user flow'), only half of the page content is localized to the new language. For clarity´s sake I´m using Korean here.
Any idea what I´m doing wrong?I´m using a Sign-In (Recommended) user flow with the Ocean Blue template.


I created Azure B2C Sign-In user flow and set localization like below:

When I ran the user flow, I faced the same issue:

Hence as a workaround set Use custom page content version as 2.1.17 and save:

Now when I ran the user flow, the complete page is displayed in Korean language:

